# Creating a menu based on cck field

Tags: routes, entities

I would like to build a custom menu structure based on cck fields.

lets say I have 2 fields in which I will type the menu item.

- parent item = field_category
- child item= field_subcategory

So in a node create form i use for '**field_category**' apples or pears and for '**field_subcategory**' green or red.

These items will also be made terms(i have a 3rd field containing tags that are equal to all menu items)

**my menu structure is like:**

- apples

  - green
  - red
- pears

  - green
  - red

my terms are: apples, pears,red, gree.

Then part 2: 
These items must be linking to a term or multiple terms.

- apples --> links to term apples

  - green --> links to term apples AND green
  - red --> links to term apples AND red
- pears

  - green
  - red

I suspect i wuould need a custom module to do so, but i am not a programmer...so I really hope someone has a solution with contrib.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to create an answer of this, but I believe the Views module may be exactly what you're looking for. Resource: http://nodeone.se/sv/node/20

Comment: Please always mention or tag your posts with version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about taxonomy term fields, then I reckon that you should investigate the [taxonomy_menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu/) or similar family of modules. In fact, looking at your other post, I suggest that you go through the entire list of taxonomy modules on Drupal in general :)

Comment: problem with taxonomy menu = I can create term on the fly into parent/child relation. taxonomy menu does not work for me on this one because it needs to have some pre-created struture.